# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_ytickslabels' when setting ytickslabels to degrees Celsius

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to set my values on the y-axis ticks in degree  Celcius by using

```
plt.get_yticks=np.arange(-40,40,10)
plt.set_ytickslabels('{}C'.format('\u00b0'))
```

I understand that I probably doing it wrong inside set_ytickslabels?

My previous code:`

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot(dates, df1['Values'], '-b',dates, df2['Values'], '-r')
ax.set_xlim(dates[0],dates[364])
```

which gives the error message. If I change to `ax.set_ytickslabels('{}C'.format('\u00b0'))`, I get the same error message, `'AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_ytickslabels')`.

```
<ipython-input-35-bc07fa12bc0e> in <module>()
     46 #ax.set_yticklabels(maxtemp15['MaxRecord15']{}C.format('\u00b0'))
     47 #ax.set_yticklabels(map(lambda x: '{:}$^\circ$C'.format(x),ax.get_yticks()))
---> 48 plt.set_ytickslabels('{}C'.format('\u00b0'))

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_ytickslabels'
```

[image: myplot]

Comment: You need `ax.set_yticklabels()`. Note that you used 'set_ytick**s**labels' with a superfluous 's'. Also `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-40,40,10))`.

Comment: @JohanC Please post this one as answer. Others will be benefited.